# Merging surfaces together to great a Bubble Gum effect with no obvious joins?

Tags: edit-mode, faces

I would like to take a string of spheres of varying sizes, line them up into a string so that they are just overlapping, and then joint them together in such a way that their faces merge into each other so that it is difficult to tell where the joins are. As if you'd take a handful of wax balls and melted them into each other and had one continuous surface.

[image]

Is this possible do do in blender?

I want to make a Princess Bubblegum ponytail\braid effect.

This will be 3D printed.

Answer (score 0):

Metaballs are probably what you need, even though it won't give a very good topology:

[image]

When you're good, if you want a better resolution, go into the *Object Data* panel and lower down the *Resolution* value. Then go into the header menu > *Object > Convert To > Mesh*. To give it a better topology and lower down the faces count, go into *Object Data > Remesh* and try for example the *Quad* option:

[image]

Comment: How do I do what you're doing in the animation?

Comment: a magician can't tell his secrets!!! These are metaballs actually (Shift A > Metaballs). I just duplicated one...